# Auto change wallpaper : what is the best approach

Tags: android, live, live-wallpaper

I'm programming a Live wallpaper displaying a simple image that I want change every 5 minutes or 5 hours.
I've too approach :
- make a thread in my engine changing wallpaper each x min/hours
- call an Intent using an AlarmManager calling my engine to change the current wallpaper

For you what's the best way (to save battery for example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go with simplicity: use a handler with a runnable that reschedules itself with postDelayed() (as in the Cube example in the SDK).  Battery drain is no concern here: wallpapers kill battery with complex animations at a rapid frame rate; all else is peanuts.